# Capture URL parameter of a link into an alert box

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to capture the URL parameter of a link `onclick` and put the URL parameter in an alert box. For example clicking on the link `users.php?user_id=200`.

How do I capture the URL parameter "user_id=200"?

I have this script but on click, the alert box appears empty:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bluetext').on('click', function(event) {
        var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
        alert(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. Just for side note. Put your Javascript at the bottom of the page. And you don't need to write everything in `$(document).ready(...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bluetext').on('click', function(event) {
    var url = window.location.href.split("?");
    alert(url[1]);
  });
});
```

> I am splitting url based on "?" question tag , which leads to "url" variable as an array having two values :

url[0] = "users.php" url[1] = "user_id=200"

And then just accessing url[1] hopes its clear now

Comment: its only able to capture when i add rel="external" to the link.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: I am splitting url based on "?" question tag , which leads to "url" variable as an array having two values : 
url[0] = "users.php"
url[1] = "user_id=200"

And then just accessing url[1]

hopes its clear now

Answer (score -1):

Your script is working fine.

If you are trying to get url prameter which are **re-written** for example,
**`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821832/capture-url-parameter-of-a-link-into-an-alert-box/29822617#29822617`**

Then ofcourse you will get a blank alert msg. This is only works with **non re-written** urls. for example, your code will only works with this kind of url. **`http://stackoverflow.com/questions.php?question_id=29821832 (just for exmaple)`**

If you're trying to get re-written url's values then you can try following,

```
var params = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(1); // ["1", "my-event"]
var first = params[0];
var second = params[1];
console.log(second) // will return "29821832". which is question id of this question.
```

But if you want to get non re-written url's value then your code is fine.

If you want some specific variable's value then you can try below.

I use this to get value of any variable,

```
function getVarVal (key) {  
  return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
}
```

Call this function as per your requirement. eg.,

```
$('.bluetext').on('click', function(event) {
    alert(getVarVal("user_id")); 
});
```